# Why Camera return extra is null?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I take a picture by standard camera:

```
  val takePicture = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
  startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_PICTURE)
```

Receiver result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {       
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            presenter!!.takeImg(this, data)
        }
    }    
}
```

Following is the code of function `takeimg`:

```
fun takeImg(context: Context, data: Intent) {       
    val imageName = CameraCommon.getFileNamePhotoReg(mImageType)        
    val bitmap = data.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
    val imageFile = CameraCommon.createImageByBitmap(context, imageName, bitmap, typePNG)
    setImg(imageFile.absolutePath)    
}
```

Following error occurrs after take picture on some devices:

```
04-23 17:53:40.153 17393-17393/jp.osaka.mozuyan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: jp.osaka.mozuyan, PID: 17393
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=6352, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/100582 typ= flg=0x1 }} to activity {jp.osaka.mozuyan/jp.osaka.mozuyan.photoreg.PhotoRegActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:764)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
                                                                   Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                      at jp.osaka.mozuyan.photoreg.PhotoRegPresenter.takeImg(PhotoRegPresenter.kt:46)
                                                                      at jp.osaka.mozuyan.photoreg.PhotoRegActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoRegActivity.kt:107)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6490)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
```

> line 46:  `val bitmap = data.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap` and 
>   `data.extras` is null

Why extra is null? 
How can save data to image file.
Thank you.

Comment: it is null because the captured image was not stored somewhere, you have to define a path where it will be stored and data will return your that URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use this code to store image into sd card then just  get the image and display the image view.if you want you can convert into bitmap also

```
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //   takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);


          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
    {  
     Manifest.permission.CAMERA,  
     Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_ST ORAGE}, 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"After permition Restart 
    App",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else {

    takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              takePicture(v);
          }
      });
    }}

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          imageView.setImageURI(file);
            }
        }
    }
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
//any path 
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
```

Comment: this is working code just copy paste and change just path where you want to store in getOutputmedia file method

Comment: android 4.4 ok, android 7.1 die after open camera.

Comment: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Mozuyan/IMG_20180424110136.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Comment: ok i understood just  maintain file uri in mainfiest file  see example -https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0